# Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I was trying to setup owncloud on WSL ubuntu but i am stuck on setting up mysql user and database since it popped up this :
`Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

but I have already installed `mysql-server` but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It happen sometimes when you install mysql-server after php. You must locate your php.ini file and edit it with the good `mysqld.sock` path.

To locate the socket, be sure that your mysql-server is running, then type `sudo locate mysqld.sock` in your terminal.

Then, you have to edit your `php.ini` file and find the `mysql.default_socket` to assign it the path of the socket. Restart apache and/or `php-fpm` if you use it and voilà !